# Python 3d plot set fixed colorscales

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I am trying to plot two 3d arrays: the first has (z) values in range `[-0.15, 0.15]` , the second one from `[-0.001, 0.001]`. When I plot, the colorscales automatically follows the datarange: how can I set a custom scale instead? I don't want to see light color for 0.001 as instead should be for 0.15. How can I fix the scale?

I share the partial code below:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import plotly.graph_objects as go


data1=np.load("test.npy")
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=data1,colorscale="viridis")])


fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=100,r=100,b=100,l=100),
    scene = dict(zaxis = dict(range=[-0.15,0.15],)),
    showlegend = False,
    width = 1000, height = 1000,
    autosize = False )
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='x',
                    yaxis_title='y',
                    zaxis_title='z'))
fig.write_image("image.pdf")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked up on the plotly API reference what kinda arguments `Surface` takes. There I see `cmin`, `cmax` and `cmix`. You can set these to tell the Surface where minimum, maximum, and midpoint, of your color scale should be. In your case, just set cmin and cmax to the appropriate values for your use case:

`go.Surface(z=data1, colorscale="viridis", cmin=-0.15, cmax=0.15)` for example