# Set static colorscale to Plotly Heatmap animation

Tags: python, animation, graph, plotly, plotly-python

I created a Heatmap animation, now I'm trying to set the colorscale in order to remain consistent with colors and values between frames.
I read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379173/python-3d-plot-set-fixed-colorscales) that cmin and cmax could do the job, but heatmaps have not such parameters.
Is there any other way to obtain the same result?

I don't know if this can be helpful but here's my plotly Figure

```
framestamps = [go.Frame(data=[go.Heatmap(
    x=lon,
    y=lat,
    z=T_series['thetao'][i],
    colorscale='aggrnyl'
)]) for i in range(300)]


fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Heatmap(
        x=lon,
        y=lat,
        z=T_series['thetao'][0],
        colorscale='aggrnyl'
    )],
    layout=go.Layout(
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type='buttons',
            buttons=[dict(
                label='Play',
                method='animate',
                args = [None, {"frame": {"duration": 250,"redraw": True},
                                "fromcurrent": True}],
            )]
        )]
    ),
    frames=framestamps
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zmin`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-zmin) and [`zmax`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-zmax) parameters of `go.Heatmap`.